# java socket freeze after a while (using threadpool)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, http, threadpool

I'm writing a program where I need to send  multiple http requests to a lot of domains using socket. I used thread pool and socket when I start the program. It starts fast then it slows down, finally it freezes (terminal is still running).

```java
public class HttpRequest implements Runnable{

    private String url;
    private Socket s;
    public boolean scanned;
    private String extension;
    
    public HttpRequest(String url,String extension) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        
        this.url=url;
        this.extension=extension;
        s=new Socket(url,80);
    
    //  
        //s.setSoTimeout(600000);
    }
    public void run() {
        String data="";
        String html="";

        try {

                PrintWriter p=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
                
                p.println("GET /"+extension+" HTTP/1.1");
                p.println("Host:"+url);
                p.println("");
        
                BufferedReader r= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                
                if(r.readLine().indexOf("200 OK")!=-1) {
                    
                    while ((data=r.readLine())!=null) {
                        html+=data;
                    
                
                        Document d =Jsoup.parse(html);
                        Element form=d.select("form").first();
                        String value=form.attr("enctype");
                        if(value=="multipart/form-data") {
                            System.out.println("value is :"+value);
                            System.out.println(" found"+this.url+"/"+extension);
                        }
                        System.out.println(d.title() + this.url+"/"+extension+"   "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            
                }}
                    else {
                    System.out.println("failed =>   "+this.url +"/"+ extension +"   "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
                   
                s.close();
            //}
        }catch(Exception e) {
    
        }
    }
    }
```

here is the main

I have a domain array which contain urls which I will make a request to

```java
ExecutorService exe= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);
for (int i =0 ; i <= domains.length-1; i++) {
    h=new handeler(domains[i]);
    exe.execute(h);

}
```

Comment: You never flush the output stream.

Comment: PrintWriter p=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); when you add true as second parameter of PrintWriter constructor you can ignore flush

Comment: 1. Why aren't you using `HttpURLConnection` for this? 2. You are swallowing exceptions yourself, which you should be logging, and closing the socket on. 3. `println()` is not sufficient. The line terminate in HTTP is `\r\n`, not whatever `println()` may do on your system. Don't use `PrintWriter` over the network: it swallows exceptions you need to know about. Use `BufferedWriter`.